# Set Expiration per message with SpringJMS

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I use MQ in my project via SpringJMS, as a broker I use ActiveMQ.
I need to set **expiration** message-based, so I tried to used `message.setJMSExpiration` but without success. All messages coming to ActiveMQ have *expiration=0*.

Does anyone has success with setting Expiration per message using Spring?

For configuring JmsTemplate I used default value `explicitQosEnabled = false;` so I expected to keep expiration from my Message props. But as I see in ActiveMQSession.class this message properties will be override:

```
        long expiration = 0L;
        if (!producer.getDisableMessageTimestamp()) {
            long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            message.setJMSTimestamp(timeStamp);
            if (timeToLive > 0) {
                expiration = timeToLive + timeStamp;
            }
        }
        message.setJMSExpiration(expiration);  
        //me: timeToLive coming from default values of Producer/JmsTemplate...
```

What I am doing wrong ? or it is just impossible with this tools.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why Spring decided to exclude this, but you can extend JmsTemplate and overload some methods, passing a timeToLive argument.

```
public class MyJmsTemplate extends JmsTemplate {

    public void send(final Destination destination,
            final MessageCreator messageCreator, final long timeToLive)
            throws JmsException {
        execute(new SessionCallback<Object>() {
            public Object doInJms(Session session) throws JMSException {
                doSend(session, destination, messageCreator, timeToLive);
                return null;
            }
        }, false);
    }

    protected void doSend(Session session, Destination destination,
            MessageCreator messageCreator, long timeToLive) throws JMSException {

        Assert.notNull(messageCreator, "MessageCreator must not be null");
        MessageProducer producer = createProducer(session, destination);
        try {
            Message message = messageCreator.createMessage(session);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Sending created message: " + message);
            }
            doSend(producer, message, timeToLive);
            // Check commit - avoid commit call within a JTA transaction.
            if (session.getTransacted() && isSessionLocallyTransacted(session)) {
                // Transacted session created by this template -> commit.
                JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(session);
            }
        } finally {
            JmsUtils.closeMessageProducer(producer);
        }
    }

    protected void doSend(MessageProducer producer, Message message,
            long timeToLive) throws JMSException {
        if (isExplicitQosEnabled() && timeToLive > 0) {
            producer.send(message, getDeliveryMode(), getPriority(), timeToLive);
        } else {
            producer.send(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As pointed by @Gary Russel, there is no need to overload anything. If you just set the explicitQosEnabled to true and then set TTL value with setTimeToLive() method, the JmsTemplate will send all messages with expiration time

Answer (score 2):

`JMSExpiration` is not the way to set an expiration. See the javadocs for `Message`...

> JMS providers set this field when a message is sent. This method can be used to change the value for a message that has been received.

In other words, it's ignored on a send - the time to live is set on the `producer.send()` method.

To expire a message set `explicitQosEnabled` to `true` and `setTimeToLive(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, I miss this point, I can set  `explicitQosEnabled` to `true`, but, producer.send() function with ttl in parameters is not available for me via JmsTemplate.

Comment: No, you set the TTL on the template; then, when explicit QOS is enabled, the template will set the TTL on the send. [See here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.java#L622).

Comment: yep, this is pretty clear, but in this case I can't use different expiration for different messages, as I need. I can't use it in concurrent mode.

Comment: [Spring Integration uses a subclass to set the priority](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/DynamicJmsTemplate.java#L29) on a per-request basis (stored in a `ThreadLocal`). You could use a similar technique and override the `getTimeToLive()` method. Just be sure to clear the thread local after each use (or in the `getTimeToLive()` method). You can also use one of the `execute` methods (e.g. one of them with a `ProducerCallback` and send the message from there.

Comment: This use case seems to stretch the benefits of using the Spring JMS Template. Especially for producing, the JMS API is pretty simple. You may consider just going straight Java + JMS.